# rose plot in matlab with z order

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot

I need to plot the 2d histogram of pictures.
The pictures are in the HSL system.
in HSl system Hue, Saturation and lightness is used instead of Red, Green, Blue.

Ranges of elements are:

- hue [0 360];
- saturation [0 100];
- lightness [0 100];

I converted image from RGB to HSL. Now I want to plot the the circular histogram of images in HSL color system.

I want something like this:

[image]

Hue around the circle from 0 to 360 based on hue amount of pixels, saturation from center to perimeter [0 100] and the number of pixels that have specific hue and saturation in z order.

for example if we have 250 pixels that their hue=90 and their saturation=50
the point 90 degree from origin and 50 distance from center of circle has 250 value in z order.

Comment: Have you tried using `rose`?

Comment: In your original question the Image was not linked, Erik somehow noticed that invisible link and fixed it. With that information I don't think `rose` is the right choice.

Comment: I vote to reopen the question, now it is clear what you want.

Comment: what should i do to open the question???

Comment: When 4 other users vote to reopen, the question is reopened. https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/

Comment: So you want a 3d plot, right? Something [like this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015a/examples/graphics/SpecifyBarWidthFor3DBarGraphExample_01.png), but with the base grid not rectangular but polar, an arrangement of ring segments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't really like Matlab's polar plotter I normally write these as Cartesian.  So say you are storing each of these (count, hue, saturation) as a column vector:

```
hue = 90;
saturation = 50;
count = 250;
x = saturation * cos(pi * hue / 180);
y = saturation * cos(pi * hue / 180);
plot3(x, y, count, '.')
```

For a more practical example:

```
hue = floor(rand(1000,1) * 361);
saturation = floor(rand(1000,1) * 100);
vals = [hue, saturation];
sorted = sortrows(vals);
[C, ia, ic] = unique(sorted, 'rows');
counts = diff(ia);
counts(end + 1) = ia(end) - length(vals) + 1;
% Not a big fan of this method so changed to find counts
% by pre-sorting and then using the index
%[C, ia , ic] = unique(vals, 'rows');
%counts = zeros(length(C), 1);
%for x = 1:length(C)
%    counts(x) = numel(find(vals(:,1) == C(x,1) & vals(:,2) == C(x,2)));
%end
x = C(:,2) .* cos(pi*C(:,1)/180);
y = C(:,2) .* sin(pi * C(:,1)/180);
plot3(x, y, counts, '.')
```

There is a way to change color based on z value if you want that but that gets a little more complicated. You can either use a mesh grid and contours or http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14677 this file will plot it.